# Error when trying to install mongodb with mongo compass

Tags: mongodb, installation, windows-installer, compass

I am getting the following error message when the MongoDB MSI tries to install mongo compass:

"Errors while parsing Compass preferences

- Unknown option "squirrelFirstrun" (while validanting preferences from: Command line)"

I don't know what to do to fix it.

I already uninstalled everything, deleted the mongo folders, restarted the computer, did the compass installation manually (outside of the mongodb installer) and the same error appears, I tested it with other versions of mongo, with other versions of compass, I checked firewall or something like, and nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass
Try to install MSI package :) exe file gave me squirrel error.

Comment: Extremely grateful, I didn't see that you had an MSI installer for compass, thanks.

Comment: I had the same error installing mongo compass today, thank you so much!