# Error while installing MongoDB Compass on Mac OS Version 10.15.7

Tags: mongodb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amkpz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRy0N.png)

I keep facing this error. I do not know how to fix it.

I restarted the mac but the error did not disappear.
I found a similar situation on StackOverflow but the guy who needed help using Windows [Error when trying to install mongodb with mongo compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74526614/error-when-trying-to-install-mongodb-with-mongo-compass)